# How to get List of of roles associated with a GCP service programatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform

To solve this I tried to use if role contains the name of the service but it doesn't work for all. For example roles associated Kubernetes has container word in the role name.

I am thinking to create a Map, but want to know if there is another way to solve this?

Comment: An IAM role does not need to have the service's name in the role name. Google documents each service and the IAM roles. Google is also continually creating new roles and modifying permission sets within existing roles. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Edit your post to clearly state the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information you have, you may use Cloud SDK to create a filter that retrieves roles associated with a specific service.

First list all IAM roles then run this command which provides a JSON output of these roles.

`gcloud iam roles list --format=json`

Next is to process the JSON output and filter the roles based on certain strings or keywords.  Here's an example using Python to process the roles JSON:

`import json`

`import subprocess`

`#Get the roles using gcloud command`

`cmd\_output = subprocess.check\_output(["gcloud", "iam", "roles", "list", "--format=json"]) roles = json.loads(cmd\_output)`

`#Filter the roles for a specific service`

`kubernetes\_roles = [role for role in roles if 'container' in role['name'].lower()]`

`for role in kubernetes\_roles: print(role['name'])`

Attached are helpful documentation for reference for your use case.[1][2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/list

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud